# OrderBy sorting complications

Tags: c#, json

When I go to sort this application and display the end results my portal is still filtered to be along the top when I'm in need of my signed at the top.

```
var orderByPortal = namecollection
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.date)
    .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Value.time)
    .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Value.signed);
```

I still have to filter the data by the date and time as well as the key.

This is a sample of my Json file.

```
{
 "Lauwers, Dan": {
    "signed": "Tuesday, June 11, 2019 @ 9:31:14 AM"
  },
  "Alexander, Betty Jean": {
    "portal": "Sunday, June 2, 2019 @ 4:14:27 AM"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What's the source? What's the goal? What's "my ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OrderByDescending,  by default it's in accending order.